# Deploying Azure Function from GitHub using PublishProfile results in "Failed to fetch Kudu App Settings Unauthorized CODE 401"

Tags: azure-functions

I used this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-github-actions?tabs=windows%2Cdotnet&pivots=method-manual) to setup a Github Action that deploys an Azure Function.

1. I created a workflow
2. I created an Azure Function
3. I added the publish profile to the Github Action as Secret.
4. I use the publish profile like this in the pipeline `publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PUBLISH_PROFILE }}`

However, executing the pipeline results in the following error:

```
Error: Execution Exception (state: ValidateAzureResource) (step: Invocation) 
Error:   When request Azure resource at ValidateAzureResource, Get Function App Settings : Failed to acquire app settings from https://<scmsite>/api/settings with publish-profile
Error:     Failed to fetch Kudu App Settings.
Unauthorized (CODE: 401)
Error:       Error: Failed to fetch Kudu App Settings.
```

I have already verified, that no networking access restrictions are in place.

Does somebody have an idea how to resolve this authentication error?

Greetings and thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Function Configuration "General settings"-Tab are is a Setting "SCM Basic Auth Publishi..." that is initially turned off. After Enabling the setting, the function app can be deployed as expected.